# python/numpy: find edges of a 2D/3D mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This question is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465162/numpy-find-indeces-of-mask-edges) but I am not sure how to apply the answer on 2D or 3D arrays.

For a simple example, using the following 2 dimensional array of shape (5,5):

```py
In [158]: a                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[158]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I want to get the indices of the edges. For this case:

```py
(array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3]))
```

Right now I shift the array in both directions/axes, compare to the original array and identify the cells that have different values:

```py
In [230]: np.nonzero(a!= np.roll(a,shift=(1,1),axis=(0,1)))                                                                                                                      
Out[230]: (array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4]), array([1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 1, 4, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Some of the indices are correct but some others not. I guess that the 4s should become 3s because of the shifts I applied but I am not sure how to correct this since I am planning to apply this to much more complicated (and bigger) mask arrays. My final goal is to apply this to 3D arrays.

I am using Python 3.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [convolve](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html) your array with an edge detection filter

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import convolve

x = np.array(
      [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

fil = [[-1,-1,-1],
       [-1, 8,-1],
       [-1,-1,-1]]

np.where(convolve(x,fil, mode='constant') > 1)
```

Out:

```
(array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]), array([1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3]))
```

The result of the convolution

```
convolve(x,fil, mode='constant')
```

Out:

```
[[-1 -2 -3 -2 -1]
 [-2  5  3  5 -2]
 [-3  3  0  3 -3]
 [-2  5  3  5 -2]
 [-1 -2 -3 -2 -1]]
```

Comment: thanks! do I just have to change the `fil` array to a (3,3,3) array and use the `convolve` function from `scipy.signal` if I want to work on three-dimensional arrays?

Comment: I updated my answer to use a multidimensional convolution, I read over your final goal. You have to use a 3D filter for a 3D array.

Comment: However, 3D edge detection is more [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11268356/14277722)

Comment: that's what I saw, I'll try to see what I can do!! thanks again